# Kubernetes 1.2 baremetal production

Tags: kubernetes

Is it recommended to deploy Kubernetes 1.2 on a bare-metal Ubuntu/ RedHat production cluster? If so, what is the recommended SDN tool  (flanneld or OvS), docker version and etcd version to use?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [getting started guide for Ubuntu](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu/). It hasn't been updated since Kubernetes v1.1.8, but it should still be applicable for v1.2.4. That getting started guide uses flannel, but you can also use [Calico](http://projectcalico.org/) ([Guide](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu-calico/)). The list of Kubernetes [getting started guides](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/) might be a good place to start.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still wondering whether 1.2.* is production ready specially in bare-metal installation. What is the most stable one? flanneld or Calico?

Comment: 1.2.* is production ready. As for flanneld vs. Calico, I don't have enough experience to give a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. docker version need to be 1.2+
2. you can found flannel/etcd version in the script of download-release.sh